# What is that airplane headphone socket?

Tags: electrical-engineering, aircraft-design, audio-engineering

I recently flew on a A380 and I saw this interesting socket.

[image]

Could someone explain to me what is the purpose of these 4 golden connections?

Comment: Are the silvery buttons magnets?

Comment: I guess they are, but I haven't checked.

Comment: This might get a better response on Aviation SE - and it's not really a question about engineering.

Comment: What is that question about, I think only engineers can figure out what this socket do.

Comment: @alephzero I agree, but in my opinion, it would be a much more polite and not destructive solution to migrate it there, instead of closing it.

Comment: @peterh answered I think?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This jack allow planes to use the air based head sets or use the electrical based headsets. It is an upgraded seat and jack that meet either audio requirements. Older planes use air power headsets normally. Headsets on planes are odd, robust and almost fit nothing to deter theft.

The golden pieces are negative positive and right left speaker but I could be wrong and the magnets conduct electricity and the golden pieces are Left negative/positive and Right negative/positive.

[image]

[image]